# Testing both in IE 8 and IE 9?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I need to test the styling of my web in both IE8 and IE9.
If I install IE9 then it will upgrade into IE8, So is there any way to install both IE8 and IE9 ?

Answer (score 3):

Use a Virtual PC for testing on older IE.

Microsoft built a set of VHDs with different variations of OS/IE which do not requires activation. But these images will expires after a few months and you will need to download a new set.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 0):

Try [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) is a great tool for web developers. You can check Browser Compatibility for Internet Explorer Versions from 5.5 to 10

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, Right now I got a way to test in IE 7, 8 and 9. after installing IE 9, When we press F12 for developer tool, there's a option for Document mode. There you can have all IE 7, 8 and 9 to test your website.

Comment: The dev tool bar is good for quick testing but doesn't fully represent older browsers (IE 7 and 8). It may be good enough for you but if not then you will need to use a virtual pc.